# C# class with dynamic properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, infragistics

I have a class that I will be using to bind to a grid.  The grid columns will correspond to the public properties of my class, all of which are `decimal?`.

Right now, in order to display all of the required info, my class includes around 30 properties.  I created these properties based off of a list that might change in the future.

It seems that hard-coding the properties and updating the class after any change is not the right way to do this but I am not sure how to create "properties" at run time (I have access to the list) and have them bind to the grid (Infragistics xamDataGrid in this case).

Any suggestions on what I can use?

Comment: Everything "might change" in the future -- is it really worth the effort to change the architecture of your application over something that *might* change? Also, won't you have to change your data grid if your class changes too?

Comment: My thinking was that if the class had access to the possible list of columns that the class properties can be dynamically created, along with the grid columns, so if anything did change, the change would be picked up automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ExpandoObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) allow dynamic assignment of properties (which are even bindable as the class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`), if that helps. They are slower though in terms of performance.

Comment: You can even access the properties if you reference it as an `IDictionary<,>` so filling it will be a snap.